# Send serial data to local server

Tags: serial, esp8266, softwareserial, wireless

I am new to arduino coding.
I am reading data from serial port and storing it in char array.
I want to send that data to the local server but it is not getting converted to string

Code :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
ESP8266WebServer server;
char* ssid = "Office RTPL";
char* password = "********";
char data[64];
char data1[64];
String str;
void setup()

{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  server.on("/",[](){server.send(200,"text/plain","Data Test");});
  server.on("/toggle",serialData);
  server.begin();
}
void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  server.handleClient();
 ;
}
void serialData()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
      {

        server.send(200,"text/plain","Data");
         for(int n=0; n<64; n++)
         {
           data[n] = (Serial.read());

         } 
         String str (data);
         server.send(200,"text/plain",str);


  else 
        {
        String no_data = "No Serial Data";
        server.send(200,"text/plain",no_data);
        delay(5000);
        }


}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in [my answer about serial communication](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-serial-communications-work-on-the-arduino/19757#19757):

> Before reading, always make sure data is available. For example, this is wrong:
>
> ```
> if (Serial.available ())
>   {
>       char a = Serial.read ();
>       char b = Serial.read ();  // may not be available
>   }
> ```
>
> The Serial.available test only ensures you have **one** byte available, however the code tries to read two. It may work, if there are two bytes in the buffer, if not you will get -1 returned which will look like 'ÿ' if printed.

In your code:

> ```
> if(Serial.available() > 0)
>     {
>     server.send(200,"text/plain","Data");
>      for(int n=0; n<64; n++)
>      {
>        data[n] = (Serial.read());
> ```

So you know that **one** byte is available, but you are reading 64. No, that won't work.

Comment: May u please guide how should i read it.

Comment: Read [how to read incoming serial data without blocking](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial).

Comment: Alternatively you could change that `if` test to be: `if(Serial.available() >= 64)`