# how to convert a line of code for arduino to receive a value

Tags: code-review

im sending the value 1500 from another MCU with

```
 fdserial_txChar(transmit, send >> 7);    // send Higher 7 bits
 fdserial_txChar(transmit, send & 0x7F);  // send Lower 7 bits
```

and was receiving it with code that looked like this

```
servo1  = fdserial_rxChar(receive) << 7;    // get Higher 7 bits
servo1 += fdserial_rxChar(receive) & 0x7F;  // get and add Lower 7 bits
```

how do i rewrite the receiving code so arduino will compile it?

Thank you.

here is the code im trying to get working

```
void setup() {
// physical pin 2=TX 3=RX  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);      // set LED pin as output
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);    // switch off LED pin
}

void loop() {
  
  if (Serial.available()) {
  //  char data_rcvd = Serial.read();   // read one byte from serial buffer and save to data_rcvd

    int data_rcvd = Serial.read() << 7;     //get Higher 7 bits
    int data_rcvd += Serial.read() & 0x7F;  //get and add Lower 7 bits




    if (data_rcvd == 1500) digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // switch LED On
    if (data_rcvd == '0') digitalWrite(3, LOW);  // switch LED Off
  }

//  if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH) Serial.write('0');    // send the char '0' to serial if button is not pressed.
//  else Serial.write('1');                           // send the char '1' to serial if button is pressed.

}
```

Comment: Please show us a complete code, not only snippets. Where are those functions defined?

Comment: i removed the second int for data_rcvd and the code compiled but did not turn on the LED

Comment: not sure if it matters but im using an attiny412

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any calls to `fdserial_rxChar()` or similar. So what is your actual problem? You eon't get good answers if you don't ask an understandable and complete question

Comment: `im sending the value 1500` ... what does that mean? ... are you sending a integer? ... are you sending text? ... something other?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few obvious problems here.

---

> ```
> if (Serial.available()) {
>  int data_rcvd = Serial.read() << 7;     //get Higher 7 bits
>  int data_rcvd += Serial.read() & 0x7F;  //get and add Lower 7 bits
> ```

You are testing that one byte is available on the serial port and then reading two bytes. Too soon. Test for two bytes if you are planning to read two.

---

> ```
> if (data_rcvd == '0') digitalWrite(3, LOW);  // switch LED Off
> ```

Why the quotes? Why not: `if (data_rcvd == 0)` ?

---

How are you intending to synchronize the sending and receiving?

Your sender is sending `HLHLHLHL` - what if the receiver starts while the low byte is being sent? You will receive `LHLHLH` which means your received data will be meaningless.

You are better off sending "readable" data, like "1500" rather than 1500, terminating with a newline, and structuring your receiving code to read until it hits a newline. That will synchronize the receiver (after the first reading, anyway).

---

For more tips about reading serial data see: [How does serial communications work on the Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-serial-communications-work-on-the-arduino)

Also [my post about serial data on my forum](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial) has code for buffering incoming serial data and waiting for a newline.

Comment: thanks for your Help Nick, you steered me towards finding my answer. is there a way to get arduino to pause/wait until it receives a specific value such as 129/0x81 ? kinda like a way to sync things up?

Comment: @benjaminnikkel The simplest solution is what I suggested in my answer. Send a "line" of data including a newline at the end. The newline will separate each reading from the next. Instead of transmitting the low-order and high-order bytes, just do a `sprintf` into a buffer, turning the number into ASCII characters, and add a newline to the end. The Arduino can read a line of data. For tips see [my post about reading serial data](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial). However the link on my own forum has better information about reading lines of data.

Answer (score 1):

the answer to my question of how to write

```
servo1  = fdserial_rxChar(receive) << 7;    // get Higher 7 bits
servo1 += fdserial_rxChar(receive) & 0x7F;  // get and add Lower 7 bits
```

so Arduino would compile it is....

```
combined = (val1 << 7) | (val2);
```